# Scrape "Button" tag with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


oLat = 33.8026087
oLong = -84.3369491999999
dLat = 33.79149
dLong = -84.32312
url = "https://ride.lyft.com/ridetype?origin=" + str(oLat) + "%2C" + str(oLong) + "&destination=" + str(dLat) + "%2C" + str(dLong) + "&ride_type=&offerProductId=standard"

driver.get(url)

content = driver.page_source

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)

print(soup)
print(url)
```

Here is my code currently. I am trying to scrape the lyft price estimate. [image]

The data is in the "button" tag. This does not show up in the html from the code I provided above. How can I get this data to show up?

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

oLat = 33.7885662
oLong = -84.326684
dLat = 33.4486296
dLong = -84.4550443
url = "https://ride.lyft.com/ridetype?origin=" + str(oLat) + "%2C" + str(oLong) + "&destination=" + str(dLat) + "%2C" + str(dLong) + "&ride_type=&offerProductId=standard"
driver.get(url)
spanThing = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , "span.sc-7e9e68d9-0 lctkqn")))
print(spanThing)
driver.quit()
```

I tried this additional code, but it doesn't find the span and class for some reason. I'm not sure why

Comment: _This does not show up in the html from the code I provided above_: How can we test our solutions if at all that doesn't works?

Comment: My question is how do I get the complete html from the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *Page Source* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) of a ***static*** element and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
oLat = 33.8026087
oLong = -84.3369491999999
dLat = 33.79149
dLong = -84.32312
url = "https://ride.lyft.com/ridetype?origin=" + str(oLat) + "%2C" + str(oLong) + "&destination=" + str(dLat) + "%2C" + str(dLong) + "&ride_type=&offerProductId=standard"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Sign up / Log in to request ride')]")))
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Console Output:

```
<html lang="en-US" class="js-focus-visible" data-js-focus-visible=""><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><script type="module">
                            if (window.performance) {
                                const toSnake = (str) => str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function($1) {return '_' + $1.toLowerCase();});

                                const measure = () => {
                                    const { timing } = window.performance;
                                    if (!timing.navigationStart) return;
                                    const al = [
                                        'event_name','sending_service','connection_end','connection_start','dom_complete',
                                        'dom_content_loaded_event_end','dom_content_loaded_event_start','dom_interactive',
                                        'dom_loading','domain_lookup_end','domain_lookup_start','fetch_start','load_event_end',
                                        'load_event_start','navigation_start','redirect_end','redirect_start','request_start',
                                        'response_end','response_start','secure_connection_start','unload_event_end',
                                        'unload_event_start','connect_start','connect_end','ms_first_paint','source','uri_path',
                                        'request_end','code','track_id','uri_href'
                                    ];
                                    const { href = '', pathname = '' } = window.location;
                                    const sE = { event_name: 'navigation_timing_absolute', uri_href: href, uri_path: pathname, sending_service: 'riderweb', source: 'riderweb' };
                                    for (let eN in timing) {
                                        const sEN = toSnake(eN);
                                        if (al.includes(sEN)) { sE[sEN] = timing[eN]; }
                                    }
                                    // iOS 11 supports ES modules, but sendBeacon not available until 11.3.
                                    if (navigator.sendBeacon) {
                                        navigator.sendBeacon('https://www.lyft.com/api/track', JSON.stringify(sE));
                                    }
                                };

                                try {
                                    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                                        measure();
                                    } else {
                                        window.addEventListener('load', measure);
                                    }
                                } catch(e) {}
                            }
                        </script><script>
var _i18n_extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };
;if(!window.__TRANSLATIONS__) window.__TRANSLATIONS__ = {};
window.__TRANSLATIONS__.locale = "en-US";
window.__TRANSLATIONS__.bundleName = "common";
if (!window.__TRANSLATIONS__.data) window.__TRANSLATIONS__.data = {};
_i18n_extends(window.__TRANSLATIONS__.data, {"%;":{"s":"OK"},"#":{"s":"Sorry, we can't find that page"},"$":{"s":"Sorry, there was an error"},"%":{"s":"Back"},"A":{"s":"No tip"},"T":{"s":"Lyft: Request a ride on the web"},"p":{"s":"Current location"},"q":{"s":"You set your pickup as \"Your Location\"{originatingAppMsg}"},"r":{"s":" in Google Maps"},"s":{"s":"To use the same pickup location, Lyft needs access to your current location."},"t":{"s":"Share your location"},"u":{"s":"Location sharing is denied"},"w":{"s":"Submit"},"x":{"s":"Save"},"y":{"s":"Confirm"},"z":{"s":"Unknown error"},"{":{"s":"Close"},"|":{"s":"Cancel"},"}":{"s":"Edit"},"~":{"s":"Delete"},"! ":{"s":"Done"},"!!":{"s":"Log out"},"!#":{"s":"Are you sure you want to log out?"},"!%":{"s":"Payment defaults"},"!&":{"s":"Add a payment method to get started."},"!(":{"s":"Add new card"},"!)":{"s":"Could not update payment method"},"!*":{"s":"Payment"},"!+":{"s":"manage your payment methods"},"!,":{"s":"Payment method"},"!-":{"s":"Card failed!"},"!.":{"s":"Payment method not supported on ride.lyft.com."},"!\u002F":{"s":"Payment method updated across Lyft apps."},"!0":{"s":"You cannot delete your only valid payment method."},"!1":{"s":"Gift cards"},"!2":{"s":"redeem gift cards"},"!3":{"s":"This field is required"},"!4":{"s":"Something went wrong. Please try again."},"!5":{"s":"Click to log out or switch accounts"},"!6":{"s":"Go back"},"!Z":{"s":"Schedule"},"!k":{"s":"schedule a ride"},"(6":{"s":"Ride"},"(7":{"s":"Rent"},"(8":{"s":"Rent a car through Lyft or our partner Sixt"},"(9":{"s":"Help"},"(:":{"s":"Business"},"(;":{"s":"Upcoming rides"},"(\u003C":{"s":"Install on Phone"},"(=":{"s":"Sign up \u002F Log in"},"(\u003E":{"s":"Log in"},"(l":{"s":"Install app"},"(m":{"s":"Free"},")z":{"s":"Not now"},"){":{"s":"Get the Lyft app"},")|":{"s":"More travel options from the palm of your hand"},")}":{"s":"From bikes to rentals and everything in between. If it gets you there, it's in the app."},"*\u003E":{"s":"Install on Desktop"},"*?":{"s":"Install on Desktop. It's free and takes up no space on your device"},"*C":{"s":"Text me a link"},"*D":{"s":"We'll send you a text with a link to download the app."},"*E":{"s":"Enter mobile phone number"},"*F":{"s":"Phone invalid"},"*G":{"s":"Refresh"},"*H":{"s":"An update is available"},",+":{"s":"View profile"},",,":{"s":"Get a ride"},",-":{"s":"Rides"},",.":{"s":"Gift cards"},",\u002F":{"s":"Promos"},",0":{"s":"Donate"},",1":{"s":"Invite friends"},",2":{"s":"Help"},",3":{"s":"Settings"},",4":{"s":"Safety Tools"},",5":{"s":"Lyft Rentals"},")d":{"s":"Log in \u002F Sign up"},")e":{"s":"You will need to log in to {action}!"},")f":{"s":"Log in"},")g":{"s":"Cancel"},"a":{"s":"Lyft and OpenStreetMap watermark"},"#L":{"s":"add promotions"},"&^":{"s":"Just now"},"&`.zero":{"s":"{minutes} minutes ago"},"&_.one":{"s":"{minutes} minute ago"},"&`.two":{"s":"{minutes} minutes ago"},"&`.few":{"s":"{minutes} minutes ago"},"&`.many":{"s":"{minutes} minutes ago"},"&`.other":{"s":"{minutes} minutes ago"},"&b.zero":{"s":"{hours} hours ago"},"&a.one":{"s":"{hours} hour ago"},"&b.two":{"s":"{hours} hours ago"},"&b.few":{"s":"{hours} hours ago"},"&b.many":{"s":"{hours} hours ago"},"&b.other":{"s":"{hours} hours ago"},"&d.zero":{"s":"{days} days ago"},"&c.one":{"s":"{days} day ago"},"&d.two":{"s":"{days} days ago"},"&d.few":{"s":"{days} days ago"},"&d.many":{"s":"{days} days ago"},"&d.other":{"s":"{days} days ago"},"&e":{"s":"Less than a minute"},"&g.zero":{"s":"{minutes} Total minutes"},"&f.one":{"s":"{minutes} Total minute"},"&g.two":{"s":"{minutes} Total minutes"},"&g.few":{"s":"{minutes} Total minutes"},"&g.many":{"s":"{minutes} Total minutes"},"&g.other":{"s":"{minutes} Total minutes"},"&i.zero":{"s":"{hours} Total hours"},"&h.one":{"s":"{hours} Total hour"},"&i.two":{"s":"{hours} Total hours"},"&i.few":{"s":"{hours} Total hours"},"&i.many":{"s":"{hours} Total hours"},"&i.other":{"s":"{hours} Total hours"},"&k.zero":{"s":"{days} Total days"},"&j.one":{"s":"{days} Total day"},"&k.two":{"s":"{days} Total days"},"&k.few":{"s":"{days} Total days"},"&k.many":{"s":"{days} Total days"},"&k.other":{"s":"{days} Total days"},"(a":{"s":"Any fare exceeding your Lyft Cash balance will be charged to your default payment method."},"(|":{"s":"Total"},"(}":{"s":"You'll pay this price unless you add a stop, change your destination, or if credit expires."},"(~":{"s":"This is an estimated range for your trip."},") ":{"s":"\u003CLink\u003ELog in\u003C\u002FLink\u003E or sign up to lock in your price and request a ride."},")?":{"s":"Driver Name:"},")@":{"s":"Driver's car image"},")A":{"s":"License Plate Number:"},")B":{"s":"Pick up"},")C":{"s":"Picked up"},")D":{"s":"Drop-off"},")E":{"s":"Dropped off"},")F":{"s":"Current location"},")c":{"s":"Close banner"},")y":{"s":"Riders"},"*I":{"s":"Add card"},"*J":{"s":"Edit {cardLabel}"},"+2":{"s":"$10"},"+3":{"s":"$8"},"+4":{"s":"$10"},"+5":{"s":"Unlimited 180-min classic rides for 24 hours"},"+6":{"s":"$15"},"+7":{"s":"Unlimited 30-min classic rides for 24 hours"},"+8":{"s":"Your payment info will be stored securely."},",#":{"s":"Please follow \u003CSupportLink\u003Ethese instructions\u003C\u002FSupportLink\u003E to allow this site to show notifications."},",$":{"s":"Notifications are blocked"},",\u003C":{"s":"Session expired"},",=":{"s":"You have been logged out. Please log back in to continue."},"!u":{"s":"Click to edit your pickup location"},"%\u002F":{"s":"You must \u003CLink\u003Elog in\u003C\u002FLink\u003E to {action}."},"&J":{"s":"Something went wrong. Unable to load your referral history. Please try again."},"7f523512b795a02fd9b9b05a1e22ff9b":{"s":"Card number"},"3effb3a930ea2ce61705bffc624e19b6":{"s":"Expiration"},"755c8f863223ae3f7ac0ac1cfe8b3072":{"s":"Name on card"},"22b715147b81b76566fa183406659069":{"s":"Country"},"4b3d5e03b24b6bbc630d15ad2251755f":{"s":"Billing address"},"e0a8872668d31bb76156a8d80a5d7a6c":{"s":"City"},"f420cf2cf310bbff1ead064745e66ec1":{"s":"State"},"8e9d206ff46216065a42a3953a63bd9f":{"s":"Province \u002F Territory"},"9dca7ddd59d7aca64aae58c7a99e16ce":{"s":"State \u002F Province"},"50be4be10369e747d757e7b2db2c9ed3":{"s":"Zip code"},"11ceb56a912fd18cc9ea1054c5405c13":{"s":"Postal code"},"5a0a89ab4fd1ceebfd9f68b88d27e685":{"s":"Save"},"45c9b92858c6ce6b50c1967661063ae8":{"s":"Cancel"},"29fc403cabcebe790ddd09c592f7e7cd":{"s":"There was a problem reading your card details. Please try again."},"1ae24aeff3771f629b2f865074b68050":{"s":"You must be logged in to add a payment method."},"275c89584bcddfbf0019d8d5a2ce6128":{"s":"You must be logged in to edit a payment method."},"2a420e791e0ec6d47cb64d5fab8376a9":{"s":"Please fill out all required fields"},"a966a08942254351695c6993e781301e":{"s":"Something went wrong. Please check your information and try again"}});
</script><meta charset="utf-8"><meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="DPR, Viewport-Width, Width, Downlink, Save-Data, Content-DPR"><link rel="home" href="https://ride.lyft.com"><link rel="canonical" href="https://ride.lyft.com"><link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.lyft.com/static/www-meta-assets/favicon.ico"><link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="192x192" href="https://cdn.lyft.com/static/riderweb/images/icons/icon-192x192.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="https://cdn.lyft.com/static/riderweb/images/icons/icon-192x192.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdn.lyft.com/static/riderweb/images/icons/icon-192x192.png"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"><meta property="og:title" content="Lyft: Request a ride on the web"><meta property="og:url" content="https://ride.lyft.com"><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"><meta name="twitter:site" content="@lyft"><meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="https://ride.lyft.com"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.lyft.com/coreui/base.4.6.5.css"><meta name="google-site-verification" content="V9fk-oLTj9Ewu7Kc6Vetf94qp8HZ3gfjxFMkn8LmZ3Y"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials"><meta name="theme-color" content="#FFFFFF"><meta name="description" content="Request a Lyft ride in a web browser on your phone, tablet, or laptop – no app download required. Get a ride from a friendly driver in minutes."><meta property="og:description" content="Request a Lyft ride in a web browser on your phone, tablet, or laptop – no app download required. Get a ride from a friendly driver in minutes."><meta property="og:image" content="/images/share.png">
.
,
<next-route-announcer><p aria-live="assertive" id="__next-route-announcer__" role="alert" style="border: 0px; clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; position: absolute; width: 1px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-wrap: normal;"></p></next-route-announcer><iframe name="__privateStripeMetricsController9540" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" role="presentation" allow="payment *" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/m-outer-93afeeb17bc37e711759584dbfc50d47.html#url=https%3A%2F%2Fride.lyft.com%2Fridetype%3Forigin%3D33.8026087%252C-84.3369491999999%26destination%3D33.79149%252C-84.32312%26ride_type%3D%26offerProductId%3Dstandard&amp;title=Lyft%3A%20Price%20estimate&amp;referrer=&amp;muid=NA&amp;sid=NA&amp;version=6&amp;preview=false" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; visibility: hidden !important; position: fixed !important; height: 1px !important; pointer-events: none !important; user-select: none !important;"></iframe></body></html>
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but it still doesn't let me access the price. That data still doesn't render for some reason.

Comment: @ColeKatz I just demonstrated how you get the complete html from the webpage. Even opening the site manually I was unable to find this piece of [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDQ5F.png).

Comment: If you inspect the price on the "select a ride type" section, it should show you this part of the HTML

Comment: I really appreciate your help though, thanks. I actually found a more direct link that helps me get the data I need